# Injecting jQuery function with dynamic parameter values

Tags: jquery, dynamic, code-injection

I'm trying to inject a jQuery function dynamically into an element. I do this dynamically because the parameters of the function may change.

As you can see the `values`,`min`,`max` properties, as well as the function parameters attached to the `stop` and `slide` event are dynamic.
Therefore I thought I'd inject the entire function dynamically, currently I insert it as a string, which obviously just inserts the text and not working code.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/service.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=" + parseCorrectURL(newURL),
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

//here I'm setting all variables that are used as values in the function to be inserted 

$('.left_nav').append('$(function () {$("#slider_pricefilter").slider({range: true,values: [' + pricemin_query + ', ' + pricemax_query + '],min:' + pricemin + ',max: ' + pricemax 
    + ',stop: function(event, ui){updateResults("price",ui.values[0]+"-"+ui.values[1]);},slide: function (event, ui) {$("#amount").val("' + currencySign + '"+ui.values[0] + " - ' + currencySign + '" + ui.values[1]);}});$("#amount").val("' + currencySign + '"+$("#slider_pricefilter").slider("values", 0) + " - ' + currencySign + '" + $("#slider_pricefilter").slider("values", 1));});');          

        }
    });
```

This is the actual function that should be inserted:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider_pricefilter").slider({
        range: true,
        values: [12, 24],
        min: 12,
        max: 24,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            updateResults("price", ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("€" + ui.values[0] + " - €" + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("€" + $("#slider_pricefilter").slider("values", 0) + " - €" + $("#slider_pricefilter").slider("values", 1));
});
```

However, this seems way too complex an approach, so there must be a better way.
Perhaps can I change the parameters of an existing function and then call that function again?
If this is the way to go, how to make sure the injected code actually works?

Comment: why not use an options dictionary where you will use the values inside the function only if they are set, just like the slide function does

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you please give details of all your code, including the event this runs under and where the variables are being retrieved from. Dynamically inserting code in to the page is almost never the correct solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the code is called within an AJAX request, I updated my post. It's hard to provide a full code sample since the variables values that are used in the function to be inserted are collected from a range of other functions. Hopefully this clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: @Surender: almost all of the values in the function are dynamic, how would I go about using those values based on whether they are set or not? Could you provide an example? e.g. for changing the `max` property? In that scenario would the function already be in my HTML where I change only the values dynamically (instead of injecting the entire function dynamically)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you are inserting the slider to the left navigation bar. insert like this

```
//this functionString will contain all your javascript.
var functionString = '(function() { alert("hi"); })()';

$(".left_nav").append("<div id='slider_pricefilter'></div>");//create the slider div in the left nav
$(".left_nav").append("<script>" + functionString + "</script>");//append the slider event to the slider_pricefilter in the left nav
```

Comment: On this line `$(".left_nav").append("<script>" + functionString + "</script>")` I'm getting: `unexpected string constant expected ')'` when appending the closing script tag...why?

Comment: Now check with you functionString. i mean what ever jquery function definition you have. The inner html of the script element should be the functionString and append a script element to the .left_nav and append the div which is slide_pricefilter to the .left_nav also.